# How to get the event when an app is killed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kill-process

I want to try  getting the event whenever my app is killed or closed by any reason or  manually or by native android devices kill.

Please help me and thanks in advance.
 i directly remove from stack then `onDestroy()` will not call. if any reason device itself close the app then also `onDestroy()` will not call.

so how is it possible to get event at anytime in any condition.
P.S: I want the event when my app is killed by some means.

Comment: yes u r right but when i directly remove from stack then onDestroy()will not call :)

Answer (score 0):

The onDestroy() callback will only be called for normal termination. If the app is force-stopped or crashes, it won't be called.

Comment: exactly my ques dude then how i got that event